# How to fix SSL error in jFrog Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am getting the error while login onto docker artifactory

> x509: certificate is valid for localhost, not docker.artifactory

I have tried the link of jfrog[1](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-use-artifactory-docker-registry-with-a-self-signed-certificate-or-a-certificate-issued-by-a-private-certificate-authority/)
and added the –insecure-registry in docker.service file
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd  -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock -insecure-registry
Restarted the docker, still getting the same error.
Not sure what exactly went wrong.

Comment: As stated in the doc you mentioned, the option must be followed by your registry domain and port: `--insecure-registry your.registry.com:XXX`. This should only be used for tests. Get a correct SSL certificate when you are ready.

Comment: I have added ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry docker-dev.artifactory.project.com:8081 -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
still no luck

Comment: As of now, I fixed by using --insecure-registry... I was setting up on a wrong machine.. it should be done on box from where it needs to be done rather on box where artifactory is installed